# VueJS - calling multiple image src as custom props

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, components, vue-component

I have a small set of icons i want to call as a custom image prop depending on what type of item the component is. Code looks like this:

```
Vue.component('otherArticles', {
      template: `

       <!-- Component -->
       <li>
           <img :src="icon.text && icon.video" alt="icon">
           <a :href="url">{{ Title }}</a>
       </li>
       `,
      props: {
          title: String,
          url: String,
          icon: [
               {
                    text: "/resources/img/icons/text-icon.svg",
                    video: "/resources/img/icons/video-icon.svg"
               }
          ]

      }
 });
```

Ideally in my html I would like to call them like this:

```
<!--Component with text icon-->
<other-articles
       icon='text' <!-- how i'd like to call the text icon as img src -->
       url="."
       title="Text article title">
</other-articles>

<!--Component with video icon-->
<other-articles
       icon='video' <!-- how i'd like to call the video icon as img src -->
       url="."
       title="Video article title">
</other-articles>
```

The img src binding is incorrect I know, i'm using it as an example of how i'm thinking it should be done, but I'm looking for any and all recommendations on how to do this correctly so I can call it the html as the example shows.

I only have these two icons and the src location for each may change but i would like to call it the same way even if i have to update the src location for either one in the future, keeping the html calls the same or similar. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First start by declaring your icon list as the following in your data function:

```
data() {
    return {
        iconList: {
            text: '/resources/text.png',
            video: '/resource/video.png',
       }
    };
}
```

Make sure to remove the list and rename the object, as you cannot have a prop and an entry in data with the same name. Then add your definition for `icon` to your props section as the following:

```
props: {
    icon: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
},
```

This tells Vue to typecheck the prop as a string, and warn when it's not present or not a string.

Now you need to update your template function to use this new prop as an key to lookup the related icon:

```
template: `
<img :src="iconList[icon]"/>
`,
```

Now you can use your component as `<comp icon="video"/>`

Comment: Ill give this a shot. Thanks @Ferrybig